# How to pass functions and variables from Context API Provider to another components?

Tags: reactjs

I need to restrict links in react router by specific user roles (I have roles stored in token).  What I'm trying to do now is:
send username & password through SignIn component to getTokens() function from custom useAuth hook on submit to then pass a boolean isModerator inside route value to ensure that the user have the required authorities for the link to show. In my case request is just not going to the server on form submit, probably because I misuse context api or react itself somehow.

So this is how my useAuth hook looks right now:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = useState(false);
  const [moderator, setModerator] = useState(false);
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState("");
  const [authorities, setAuthorities] = useState([]);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const signIn = async (e, username, password) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await getTokens(username, password);

    if (result) {
      console.log("User has signed in");
      setAuthed(true);
    }
  };

  const isModerator = async () => {
    const result = await getAccessTokenAuthorities();

    if (result) {
      console.log("User is admin");
      setModerator(true);
    }
  };

  const getTokens = async (username, password) => {
    const api = `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/public/signIn?username=${username}&password=${password}`;

    const res = await axios.get(api, {
      withCredentials: true,
      params: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      },
    });
    const data = await res.data;

    setAccessToken(data["access_token"]);
    setRefreshToken(data["refresh_token"]);

    console.log(data);

    return accessToken, refreshToken;
  };

  const getAccessTokenAuthorities = async () => {
    const api = `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/public/getAccessTokenAuthorities`;

    const res = await axios.get(api, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });
    const data = await res.data;

    setAuthorities(data);

    let vals = [];

    authorities.forEach((authority) => {
      vals.push(Object.values(authority));
    });

    const check = vals.filter((val) => val.toString() === "MODERATOR");
    if (check.length > 0) return !isModerator;

    console.log(authorities);

    return isModerator;
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        authed,
        setAuthed,
        moderator,
        setModerator,
        getTokens,
        getAccessTokenAuthorities,
        username,
        password,
        setUsername,
        setPassword,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

And this is me trying to use AuthContext in SignIn component:

```
 import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../hooks/useAuth";
import { AuthContext } from "../hooks/useAuth";

const SignIn = (props) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const userDetails = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Вход</h1>
      <form
        method="get"
        onSubmit={(e) => auth.signIn(e)}
        encType="application/json"
      >
        <label htmlFor="username">Имя пользователя</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          onChange={(e) => userDetails.setUsername(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <label htmlFor="password">Пароль</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          onChange={(e) => userDetails.setPassword(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        Вход
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

SignIn.propTypes = {};

export default SignIn;
```

Here is how I set my AuthProvider in index.js:

```
    import React from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
 import "./index.css"; import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
 import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
 import Inventory from "./components/Inventory";
 import SignIn from "./components/SignIn";
 import { AuthProvider } from "./hooks/useAuth";
 import App from "./App";
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
 root.render( 
<React.StrictMode>
 <BrowserRouter> 
<AuthProvider> 
<Routes> 
<Route path="/"
 element={<App />}>
</Route> 
<Route path="api/v1/public/signIn"
 element={<SignIn />}>
</Route> 
<Route path="api/v1/moderator/inventory" element={<Inventory />} >
</Route>
 </Routes>
 </AuthProvider> 
</BrowserRouter> 
</React.StrictMode> );
    
   reportWebVitals();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating 2 instances of context when you initialize 2 variables of it.
Both of these variables are behaving as separate instances of context. Its like when an object is initialized from a constructor.

All the methods you've passed to context Provider are available on `const auth=useAuth()`. Inside your Signin component, you're calling `userDetails.setUsername()` for changing value of username and to submit the form you're calling `auth.signin`.

You can simply use `auth.setUsername(e.target.value)` and `auth.setPassword(e.target.value)`. For submitting form use `auth.signin()`

```
const SignIn = (props) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
// const userDetails = useContext(AuthContext); No need to initialize this one

  useEffect(() => {
// here in this log you will see all the methods are available from context provider
    if (auth) console.log(auth);
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Вход</h1>
      <form
        method="get"
        onSubmit={(e) => auth.signIn(e)}
        encType="application/json"
      >
        <label htmlFor="username">Имя пользователя</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          onChange={(e) => auth.setUsername(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <label htmlFor="password">Пароль</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          onChange={(e) => auth.setPassword(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        Вход
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Also, you're not passing signIn function to context provider. If you want to use it in components, you should add it inside value props of context provider